# Some people have several separate policies how can I filter the data so I can only see the most recent contact date for each email address?

Tags: sql

My data looks like the below

| Policy | ContactDate | Email | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| POL1 | 17:02:2021:11:51:41 | JON@gmail | Jon |
| POL2 | 17:02:2021:15:10:44 | JON@gmail | Jon |
| PO3 | 13:02:2021:09:41:00 | Pete@aol | Pete |
| POL4 | 14:02:2021:05:40:15 | Kate@yahoo | Kate |
| POL4 | 14:02:2021:18:15:06 | Kate@yahoo | Kate |

Some people have several separate policies how can I filter the data so I can only see the most recent contact date for each email address? So my results would be Row 2,3 & 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
SELECT MAX(ContactDate), Email, Name
FROM Table
GROUP BY Email, name;
```

Comment: Just to be clear - original question asks for rows 2,3 & 4 - this is not achievable with the (reworked) solution from ex4 - row 4 has an earlier timestamp than row 5 - So question might need revising to show rows 2,3 & 5 ?

Comment: I meant 5 not 4 , clearly didn't read it after I typed it! Thank you :)